# Object is not added to the array with html form submission

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form that calls the saveInput function when submitting it. Each time of submission, it is supposed to add the input values to the array as an object. But when it is submitted, the console shows for a moment that there is an array with one object. Then the array disappears. Here is the form and the function:

```html
<form onsubmit="saveInput()" class="column-full item" id="input-form">
            <label for="image-url" required >Image URL: </label><br>
            <input oninput="loadImage()"  class="row" type="text" id="image-url" placeholder="Type the URL of your image" required /><br>
            <label for="image-title">Title: </label><br>
            <input class="row" type="text" id="image-title" required /><br>
            <label for="image-details">Notes: </label><br>
            <input class="row" type="text" id="image-details" required /><br>
            <button class="row" type="submit" value="Save" id="btn_save">Save</button>
</form>

<script>
    let journalPages = [];

    function saveInput(events){
      let newPage={
        id: Date.now(),
        imageURL: document.getElementById('image-url').value,
        imageTitle: document.getElementById('image-title').value,
        imageDetails: document.getElementById('image-details').value
      }

      journalPages.push(newPage);               //Add the new entry object to the array
      document.querySelector('form').reset();   //Clear the form
      console.warn('added', {journalPages});
      localStorage.setItem('MyPage', JSON.stringify(journalPages));

  } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `events.preventDefault` function on the top of your `saveInput` function like this:

```
<form onsubmit="saveInput()" class="column-full item" id="input-form">
            <label for="image-url" required >Image URL: </label><br>
            <input oninput="loadImage()"  class="row" type="text" id="image-url" placeholder="Type the URL of your image" required /><br>
            <label for="image-title">Title: </label><br>
            <input class="row" type="text" id="image-title" required /><br>
            <label for="image-details">Notes: </label><br>
            <input class="row" type="text" id="image-details" required /><br>
            <button class="row" type="submit" value="Save" id="btn_save">Save</button>
</form>

<script>
    let journalPages = [];

    function saveInput(events){
      events.preventDefault();
      let newPage={
        id: Date.now(),
        imageURL: document.getElementById('image-url').value,
        imageTitle: document.getElementById('image-title').value,
        imageDetails: document.getElementById('image-details').value
      }

      journalPages.push(newPage);               //Add the new entry object to the array
      document.querySelector('form').reset();   //Clear the form
      console.warn('added', {journalPages});
      localStorage.setItem('MyPage', JSON.stringify(journalPages));

  } 
</script>
```

Comment: Can you explain how to do that, please?

Comment: on your `saveInput` function add this line  `events.preventDefault();`  (the code in my answer already has it)